# Unable to connect amazon MYSQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, amazon-web-services

hi In hibernate properties file i just change the URL from my local server to amazon by doing this its gives me an error like .

```
"The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor27.newInstance(Unknown Source)"
```

url I used to connect is like

```
jdbc:mysql://mysqlinstance.cccq0sbejebc.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/database?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

by changing URL to my local its working fine
please help

Comment: Did you open the security group?

Comment: how to open security group i don't have knowledge of security group ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the steps below to add IP address of your server to the RDS Security Group.

1. In the RDS AWS Console go to the description of your RDS instance. It looks similar to below.

[image]

2. Click on the security group it will take you to the security group setting of the RDS instance.

[image]

3. In the connection type select CIDR/IP and in the CIDR/IP to Authorize text box add your server IP address in this format 2.3.4.5/32 where 2.3.4.5 is your server IP address. And then your server will be able to communicate with the RDS.

Comment: can you please tell 2.3.4.5/32 2.3.4.5 is IP and but can you tell what is 32 ??